# Replicate database state at a specific point in time to a remote server (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 R2 and I need to replicate the content of a database for example each hour. It's really important that I can trigger this replication and that only the  data, that were in the database at the time the replication was triggered, are replicated.

So let's say I have the two following servers:

- Server A (productive server)
- Server B (failover server)

Is it possible to do a snapshot on server A and then replicate this snapshot to the remote server B? Every changes that occurred after the snapshot was created shouldn't be replicated to the server B!

Thanks for your help!

Regards, Alain

Comment: Could you use log shipping for this? T-Logs can be restored point-in-time.

Comment: you also use [snapshot replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151832.aspx)